# Where can I find documentation on how to use the PhotoShop UI Toolkit?

Tags: photoshop-script

I am trying to create a script for drawing a frame around my photographs. I already have actions that will do that, but they're not perfect. I always have to tweak them after the frame is created.

The main fundamental problem I see with actions is that there can be no user interface. I want the user to be able to select parameters such as frame size, color, line width, and so on, before the frame is actually drawn. I would also like to give the user the ability to save their selections and recall them the next time the script is used.

The [PhotoShop Scripting Guide](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop-scripting-guide-2020.pdf) just has a tiny section at the end about user interfaces. It says "Adobe provides the ScriptUI component, which works with the ExtendScript JavaScript interpreter to provide JavaScript scripts with the ability to create and interact with user interface elements." And it provides [this link](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/ScriptUI.html). But that link only goes to a page that describes, very incompletely, recent changes to that component. Can anyone tell me where I can find documentation that will teach me to use that component?

And in case it matters to anyone, I posted this identical question on Reddit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most comprehensive source is the [ScriptingUI for Dummies pdf book](https://adobeindd.com/view/publications/a0207571-ff5b-4bbf-a540-07079bd21d75/92ra/publication-web-resources/pdf/scriptui-2-16-j.pdf) by Peter Kahrel.

There's also an [amasing WYSIWYG editor](https://scriptui.joonas.me) by Joonas Pääkkö — it makes the process so much easier.

Answer (score 1):

There is also the [scriptUI](https://adobeindd.com/view/publications/a0207571-ff5b-4bbf-a540-07079bd21d75/92ra/publication-web-resources/pdf/scriptui-2-16-j.pdf) from Adobe.

And funnily enough, in the Adobe document, it states: "If you want to create your own ScriptUI dialogs but reading this guide is too much for you, head for Joonas Pääkkö’s excellent dialog builder at [https://scriptui.joonas.me/](https://scriptui.joonas.me)"